# PDO Array from MySQL Query into Insert Queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array which I am getting from the following PDO:

```
$sqlQry = "SELECT Devices.dID FROM Friends LEFT OUTER JOIN Devices ON Friends.fID = Devices.dUID WHERE Devices.dID IS NOT NULL GROUP BY Devices.dID";
$db = getConnection();
$sth = $db->prepare($sqlQry);
$sth->execute();
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

the array returns:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ([dID] => 2[0] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [dID] => 3 [0] => 3 ))
```

For each one of the dID values I need to run an insert query that takes the dID and inserts it into a table in the same database with outer values.

```
$sqlIns = "INSERT INTO messages (dID, message, status") VALUES (?,?,?);
```

The message and status will be held in a variable

Can any one help me out with this one?

Comment: Why don't you do this all in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one query. See the documentation: [INSERT ... SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT into messages (dID, message, status) 
SELECT Devices.dID, ?, ? 
FROM Friends 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Devices ON Friends.fID = Devices.dUID 
WHERE Devices.dID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY Devices.dID
```

The PDO would look something like this:

```
// database connection
$conn = new PDO(...);

// new data
$message = 'xxx';
$status = 'yyy';

// query
$sql = "INSERT into messages (dID, message, status) 
    SELECT Devices.dID, ?, ? 
    FROM Friends 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Devices ON Friends.fID = Devices.dUID 
    WHERE Devices.dID IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY Devices.dID";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($message,$status));
```

Comment: thanks would you post how you would do it I am new to PDO and it would really help me

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $result as $idValue ) {
    $sqlIns = "INSERT INTO messages (dID, message, status) VALUES ($idValue[0],?,?)";
}
```

That should do the trick. Though I am not sure why are you using `fetchAll`.